# Problems with Umlaute in HTML email

Tags: php, html, email, encoding, utf-8

I am sending an HTML email that contains an ü-Umlaut in it's body. I'm setting the encoding to UTF-8 in the HTML `<head>`, as well as in the mail header:

HTML

```
$body = '<html>
            <head>
                <title>My Title</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Here comes the ü-Umlaut</h1>
                ...
                <p>Here comes an ö-Umlaut</p>
            </body>
        </html>';
```

Mail header

```
$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

When viewing the email on my iPhone, I see a `Ã¼` instead of the `ü`. But when viewing the mail on my gmail account, the `ü` is displayed correctly. The `ö` is displayed correctly on both devices.

A colleague of mine correctly views the `ü` in his email client. But he doesn't see the `ö`, but a square with a question mark inside (probably something like `�`).

Now what's gone wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: What happens when you change it to the HTML special character `&uuml;`?

Comment: Try using the quoted-printable Transfer-Encoding - otherwise your email will probably go right to SPAM ;)

Comment: @geevCookie That will most likely display it correctly. But that's one advantage of UTF8, that I don't have to care about using HTML special chars, isn't it?

Comment: You should also be using `Content-Type: multipart/alternative`, with a text part as well as your HTML part, to enable support for text-only clients. See http://isnotspam.com/ for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your php file also forces UTF-8:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

same counts for the calling html page:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

or if you use ajax:

```
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: './sendemail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; utf-8",
```

All participants must use the same charset. Especially the final email client:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=UTF-8>
```

Comment: even with the html part as suggested, when i send it through python to other emails, the umlauts are messed up. Do you have any idea?